# How to check if an associative array contains a value and only that value?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if an associative array contains a certain value and only that value. So for example key `choice` needs to contain the value `Afhalen`.

Below an example array:

```
Array
(
    [Test product1644] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 644
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 20,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 1644
            [choice] => Bezorgen
        )

    [Test product2644] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 644
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 90,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 2644
            [choice] => Bezorgen & Opbouw
        )

    [Test product3644] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 644
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 100,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 3644
            [choice] => Bezorgen & Afhalen
        )

    [Test product4644] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 644
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 200,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 4644
            [choice] => Afhalen
        )

)
```

Above array should return false since there are more `choice` keys with values other than `Afhalen`.

Below array should return true since `choice` always contains `Afhalen`:

```
Array
(
    [Test product4644] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 644
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 200,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 4644
            [choice] => Afhalen
        )

    [Test product4646] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 649
            [product] => Test product
            [price] => 200,00
            [picture] => images/_bad_noimg.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => test-product-2
            [catalias] => stormbanen-huren
            [prodoptie] => 4644
            [choice] => Afhalen
        )
)
```

I've found a question on how to do this using javascript but nothing on how to do it using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hasOnlySingleChoice = true;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['choice'] !== 'Afhalen') {
        $hasOnlySingleChoice = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function distinctValue($array, $value){
       foreach($array as $item){
             if( $item[‘choice’] != value ) {
                  return false;
              }
       }
       return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter to achieve this,

```
$a = array_filter($array, function($value,$key) {
    return $item['choice'] != 'Afhalen'; // filter all which are not equal to 'Afhalen'
});
echo (count($a) > 0 ? false : true); // if there are values with choice  
                                        //other than Afhalen then false else true
```